# angular.element with and without `document.querySelector`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my directive I want to access a id from my DOM. I integrated jQuery in my project, But the problem is two way I can access my desired DOM:

```
var myEl = angular.element('#divID');
```

And

```
var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divID'));
```

My question is what is the difference between them?

Comment: It is new to me that you can use directly `angular.element( '#divID');`. Are you sure that you really retrieve the element correctly?

Comment: @quirimmo yes that will retrieve the correct element.

Comment: yes, but i don't know how and why.

Comment: See my updated answer below: `angular.element` is equivalent to `jQuery` because angular is built on top of jQuery.

Comment: did you include also jQuery before the inclusion of angularjs?

Comment: yes i did  include jquery before angularjs

Comment: try commenting out that line and (hopefully) the element should be not retrieved in the first way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's working also in the first way is that you included jQuery before AngularJS, so actually when you call `angular.element` angular returns to you an instance of $, and you are able to use angular.element with selectors too.

Otherwise AngularJS has a built-in version of jQuery that is jQlite, and you need to pass the HTML element inside `angular.element` in order to get back a jQlite object, that is a standard jQlite object with some more properties added by AngularJS.

This snippet includes jQuery after AngularJS. In this case that selector doesn't work.

```js
console.log(angular.element('#test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  ciao
</div>
```

This snippet includes jQuery before instead, and the selector actually works:

```js
console.log(angular.element('#test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  hello
</div>
```

p.s. I don't know if it is an issue with the actually code snippet engine here in stack overflow, because I usually use `angular.element` passing the HTML element, but I noticed a really decrease of performances using directly the selector with `angular.element`.
The following snippet will use the `angular.element` passing the HTML even if jQuery is included before AngularJS, and it seems to run really really faster than the previous one. You can compare them. But again, maybe it just depends on the current snippet engine in SO

```js
console.log(angular.element(document.querySelector('#test')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: yep done :) you are welcome. Btw my suggestion is that if you have to use angular.element, provide HTML elements as parameters, otherwise use directly $/jQuery if you want to use jQuery

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `angular.element('#divId');` is working is that `angular.element` is a reference to jQuery (as long as jQuery is also included in the project before Angular, otherwise the default is jQuery lite which comes with some limitations). The standard behavior when `jQuery(queryString)` is called is to return a jQuery-wrapped element list of element(s) matching the passed in `queryString`.

`document.querySelector` is a native browser API. Over time, browsers have implemented more and more APIs. One of jQuery's goals is compatibility with many browsers, and it allowed one to select elements with a query selector before many browsers had implemented the native `document.querySelector`.

As you can see at http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector -  `document.querySelector` is now supported natively by all major browsers.

However, in your case, there is a third and arguably more efficient option since you avoid the browser having to parse the `'#divID'` string:

```
var myEl = angular.element(document.getElementById('divID')); // note no #
```

Comment: I think that his question is why also directly `var myEl = angular.element( '#divID');` is working

Comment: Thanks @quirimmo I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @NateFerrero what angularjs uses by default is jQlite, which is a lite version of jQuery. If you include jQuery before angularjs, then angular will use the included jQuery. But if you are only with angularjs, you actually use jQlite. It's pretty different, you don't have all the methods, and also the methods you have are different and you have limitations with them. For example the `find()` method in jQuery accepts any kind of selectors, in jQlite you can only provide elements tags

Comment: @quirimmo yes you are correct. Updated again. Thanks!